# How to recover project from Adobe XD link?

Tags: android, ios, prototype, recover, adobe-xd

I developed a prototype for an app on Adobe XD and published it some months ago. I had to format my computer and lost the project. Is there any way to recover it from the link or any cloud it is automatically stored to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using Adobe Creative Cloud, you might save your work there. If you saved on your local machine, depends on your operation system there are tools which helps to save your data but it is not 100% guarantee.